# SQL server Procedure modification required

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which produces output like:

```
Success  Fail  Progress
----------------------------
   1      2       3
```

But I want the output to be:

```
Recieved  Count
----------------
success     1
----------------
fail        2
----------------
progress    3
```

Please can someone help me get this output from my sql server.

The current SQL:

```
select 
    sum(case when status='AK' then 1 else 0 end) as 'SUCCESS', 
    sum(case when status='E' then 1 else 0 end) as 'FAILURE', 
    sum(case when status NOT IN('AK','E')then 1 else 0 end) as 'PENDING' 
from t 
where [rec_datetime] BETWEEN '2008-02-11' AND DATEADD(DAY,1,'2008-02-11')
```

Comment: can you post the code for your select statement as it is now?

Comment: select sum(case when status='AK' then 1 else 0 end) as 'SUCCESS',
  sum(case when status='E' then 1 else 0 end) as 'FAILURE',
  sum(case when status NOT IN('AK','E')then 1 else 0 end) as 'PENDING'
   from t
  where  [rec_datetime] BETWEEN '2008-02-11' AND DATEADD(DAY,1,'2008-02-11')

Comment: Sure. Change your stored procedure output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your select statement with

```
select 'Success' as Received, sum(case when status='AK' then 1 else 0 end)  as [count]
 from t where [rec_datetime] BETWEEN '2008-02-11' AND DATEADD(DAY,1,'2008-02-11')
union all
select 'Fail', sum(case when status='E' then 1 else 0 end) 
 from t where [rec_datetime] BETWEEN '2008-02-11' AND DATEADD(DAY,1,'2008-02-11')
union all
select 'Progress' , sum(case when status NOT IN('AK','E')then 1 else 0 end)
 from t where [rec_datetime] BETWEEN '2008-02-11' AND DATEADD(DAY,1,'2008-02-11')
```

Comment: 1 small question Jamie...is using 'Between' the Correct method to extract dates..my main motive was to select records on a date choosen from a calendar and find matching data..because otherwise it gives me zero records as in table it is there with timestamp

Comment: between is inclusive, so if your data contains records where rec_datetime is 12-02-2008 00:00:00 they will be included in your results.  for your example, if you only want data from 11/02/2008, then use where [rec_datetime] >= '2008-02-11' and [rec_datetime] <  '2008-02-12'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNPIVOT` to move columns to rows:

```
SELECT b.[Received], b.[Count]
FROM (SELECT[Success] = 1, [Fail] = 2, [Progress] = 3) a
UNPIVOT ([Count] FOR [Received] IN ([Success], [Fail], [Progress])) b
```

**Output**

```
Received    Count
----------- -----------
Success     1
Fail        2
Progress    3
```

Answer (score -1):

tough without seeing your code or your data, but something like this might work:

```
select 'success' As Recieved, Success As [Count] from mytable
union all
select 'fail', Fail  from mytable
union all
select 'progress',  Progress from mytable
```

Comment: Good one, but a quick question: why you put an [Count] not Count?

Comment: This isn't `from mytable`.. this is `from aStoredProc`

Comment: and what do you think the stored procedure is querying from? a table perhaps?

Comment: @LifeScript Count is a keyword so it's better practice to put it inside square brackets if using it as an alias. I think other RDBMS vendors also use double quotes for things like that.

Comment: thank you =], but I would rather name a different one, like T_count

Comment: is that a good practice to get rid of all the keywords? @E.J. Brennan